# Sleep() function inside a infinite while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop, sleep

Is it possible for sleep function inside a while loop? I have this while loop which goes to infinity. When I add `time.sleep(10)` it breaks out of the loop after the second try. Is it possible to `time.sleep()` inside an infinite loop?

```
import time as time
while True:
    for i in range(2):
       num = int(input("Enter an integer: "))
       print("The double of",num,"is",2 * num)
    print('10')
    time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the error - works fine for me

Comment: No it does not break out of the loop.

Comment: The code works fine!

Comment: for me it is breaking out of the loop after the the second time when it asked for an integer!

Comment: Did you try inserting a float or a string?

Comment: There's no reason why `time.sleep(10)` should break out of the loop. How are you running the script, can you post a transcript of the session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code as you post it works just fine. The problem may (as mentioned by @Guy) be cause when the user inputs something that is not exactly an int. That is because `input` returns a string and `int` tries to get an integer out of that string e.g. in. On failing to read `int` raises a `ValueError`. e.g.

```py
>>> num = input("Enter an integer: ")
Enter an integer: 12.5
>>> num 
'12.5'  <-- num, the return of input is a string
>>> int(num) <-- int fails to get a integer out of the string num
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '12.5'
```

So you need to handle that case explicitly by a `try except` block

```py
import time as time
while True:
    for i in range(2):
       try: 
           num = int(input("Enter an integer: "))
           print("The double of",num,"is",2 * num)
       except ValueError: 
           print("Please enter a valid integer")
    print('10')
    time.sleep(10)
```